# using ceiling function within Google Sheets QUERY

Tags: google-sheets

[edited]

I'm trying to use the QUERY function in Google Sheets to summarize the data from another sheet.

The link to my example spreadsheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b3APKeWQ9UjJp4vRx_JDQWv8tN5_caYPcTIaCcGto34/edit?usp=sharing

It contains three sheets:

monthly_expenses provides a list of expenses that recur and are the same every month.

other_expenses is a list of expenses that occur a small number of times over the course of the year.  The last 12 entries are transcribed from monthly_expenses.

expenses_by_month should have one line per month, in chronological order, with the total for each month.  The third column should provide the amount from the previous column but rounded up to the next multiple of $100. It is generated by a query:

=query(other_expenses!B1:C,"select C, sum(B), 100*((sum(B)+99.99)%100) group by C order by C", -1)

What I don't know how to do is

order the rows chronologically rather than alphabetically

compute the third column correctly.  Clearly % is the wrong operation, but I've not figured out how to truncate.

Apparently the regular Sheets functions are not available within QUERY since it uses the "Google Visualization API" instead.

I've tried searching that API documentation for a "ceiling" function with no success. I've also not found a way to go from month name to month ordinal.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: pls share a spreadsheet, what is the format of monthes in column C (are they dates or text?) the roundup function can be added after query by arrayformula

Comment: As Mike mentioned, I think it would be better if we had a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can understand what is the expected result and what kind of data you are working with. You don't have to share the exact same data you are using but you can create a sample spreadsheet with similar information and paste the link so that we can check it.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special recognition to The God of Biscuits for their answer.

player0's answer and comments were also very helpful.

I eventually came up with:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({other_expenses!B:C, TEXT(MONTH(1&other_expenses!C:C), "00")},"select sum(Col1), Col2, Col3 where Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col2, Col3 ORDER BY Col3", ),"select Col2, Col1, Col1 + 100 - ((Col1 + 100) % 100)"),"select * LABEL Col1 'month', Col2 'total', Col3 'transfer amount'"))`

Why are here three nested queries?

The innermost query adds the month number and performs the aggregation and sorting.

The query around that just adds a column for the rounded up amount.  This didn't need to be a separate query but allowed me to use a column reference rather than an expression to abstract the SUM.

The outermost query just adds column labels.  I couldn't figure out how to refer to the third column of the second query in a labels clause for that query.

Key observations:

The query language doesn't have a ceiling operator, but it does have remainder/mod (%), so rounding X up to the next $100 can be done by X + 100 - ((X + 100) % 100).

The query language doesn't have a way to convert a month name string like "January" to a month number like 1, but Google Sheets has a way to do it.  The month number needs to be computed in Google Sheets and passed in to the query.  I was unable to find good documentation for that so I got it from your suggestions plus alot of trial and error.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end! Re. the labelling issue, you would refer to the third column in the label clause exactly as you define it in the select clause, i.e. Col1 + 100 - ((Col1 + 100) % 100). Arguably keeping the outer QUERY is better from a readability perspective though, in which case you don't actually need the 'select *' clause because omitting it is the same as selecting all columns.

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact possible to do rounding within a QUERY, but it needs to be done indirectly with a bit of maths. To do so, you have to exploit the (undocumented,  I think) modulo operator (%). Replicating the answer given by player0:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(query(query({B:C,month(C:C&1)}, "select Col2, sum(Col1), Col3 where Col2 is not null group by Col2,Col3 order by Col3"),"select Col1,Col2,(Col2+100)-(Col2+100)%100"),"offset 1",0))
```

What we are doing here within the query is adding 100 to each amount, then from this subtracting (amount+100) modulo 100, which rounds the answer back down to the nearest hundred (achieving the same result as you requested). It should be possible to do account for other rounding scenarios by changing the addend and modulus accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  The suggestions provided so far seem too complicated though.  My expectation was that the query language would have a ceiling or a round function and I just wasn't finding it.

I tried something based on the modulus suggestion, with surprising results.  The query

=query(OtherExpenses!B1:C,"select C, sum(B), (sum(B)+99.99)%100 group by C order by C", -1)

produced 1922.99 and 22.98 for the 2nd and 3rd columns.  I don't know what % is meant to do, and the Google query language documentation is not forthcoming about it, but that is clearly not mod.

Comment: Interesting... but to re-iterate the comments made elsewhere it's very difficult to diagnose what you are seeing without a shared spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm trying to decompose and understand the formula from player0.

In the Google Sheets documentation I learned that {} syntax defines an array which can serve as a range, for example as an input to QUERY.

I see that the rounding and the sort key are computed using the Google Sheets language rather than the Google Visualization API Query Language, presumably because the latter isn't up to it, or its documenttation is too incomplete to discover such facility.

<continued>

Comment: I'm experimenmting with constructing an array expression that includes the sort key.  Ive also decided that, for the purpose of my application, I can turn the month name into a date with something like

DATEVALUE("" & C & " " & 7 & " " & YEAR(NOW()))


I've created a sheet to experiment in.  It's shared here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ma69B3RgOx0Uf4kz-pSwYqtFR3NCDCw8j5EPzMyc38o/edit?usp=sharing

Expenses contains sample raw data.  Redux is where I'm experimenting with queries.

Comment: I'm experimenmting with constructing an array expression that includes the sort key.  Ive also decided that, for the purpose of my application, I can turn the month name into a date with something like

DATEVALUE("" & C & " " & 7 & " " & YEAR(NOW()))


I've created a sheet to experiment in.  It's shared here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ma69B3RgOx0Uf4kz-pSwYqtFR3NCDCw8j5EPzMyc38o/edit?usp=sharing

Expenses contains sample raw data.  Redux is where I'm experimenting with queries.

<cont>

Comment: I'm currently stuck trying to create an array (to query against) that includes the two columns from Expenses and an additional column for the date calculated from Expenses!A.  I don't understand the error message that Redux!A27 is getting.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 QUERY({Expenses!B1:B, TEXT(MONTH(Expenses!C1:C&1), "00×")&Expenses!C1:C}, 
 "select Col2,sum(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label sum(Col1)''", ), 
 ROUNDUP(QUERY({Expenses!B1:B, TEXT(MONTH(Expenses!C1:C&1), "00×")&Expenses!C1:C}, 
 "select sum(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 label sum(Col1)''", ), -2)}),,9^9)), 
 "(^\d+×)", ), " "))
```

[image]

Comment: @user3159619 hard to tell if you meant January as a text string or as a date value. provided answer accounts for text string

Comment: "January" as a text string, as it is in the example spreadsheet.

Comment: The formula suggested by player0 gets a #VALUE error (with no explanation), even after I remove the newlines.  I hope what I need to do is no where near that complicated.  There are some choice snippets that have been quite helpful though.

Comment: This formula gives the right ceiling amount

=query(query(other_expenses!B1:C, "select C, sum(B) where C is not null group by C"), "select Col1, Col2, Col2 + 100 - ((Col2 + 100) % 100)")

I'n now trying to add the month ordinal.

This gives me 'amount' and 'month' as I expect:

={other_expenses!B1:B, other_expenses!C1:C}

just as

={other_expenses!B1:C}

does.

but this gets "ARRAY_ROW parameter 3 has mismatched row size":
={other_expenses!B1:B, other_expenses!C1:C, MONTH((other_expenses!C1:C)&1)}

Comment: @MarkNahabedian for array error see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039876/array-literal-an-array-literal-was-missing-values-for-one-or-more-rows/58042211#58042211 also see if this solves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77475613/5632629 (simpler syntax)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(
 {other_expenses!B:C, TEXT(MONTH(1&other_expenses!C:C), "00")}, 
 "select Col2,sum(Col1),100*((sum(Col1)+99.99)%100),Col3 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col2,Col3 
  order by Col3
  label sum(Col1)'',100*((sum(Col1)+99.99)%100)''", ), 9^9, 3))
```

[image]