# Virtually blank column in array?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language

I use this formula in Google Sheets:

```
=SORT({SORT({'Discord-D'!B2:B, 'Discord-D'!A2:A, 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Discord-D'!G2:G = "", "", IF('Discord-D'!C2:C <> "", "Removed", "Processing"))), 'Discord-D'!H2:H, 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Discord-D'!C2:C <> "", 'Discord-D'!G2:G, IFERROR(REPLACE('Discord-D'!G2:G, LEN('Discord-D'!G2:G)-3, 4, "****")))), 
                 'Discord-D'!I2:I}, ROW('Discord-D'!A2:A), FALSE); SORT({'Facebook-D'!B2:B, 'Facebook-D'!A2:A, 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Facebook-D'!E2:E = "", "", IF('Facebook-D'!C2:C <> "", "Removed", "Processing"))), 'Facebook-D'!F2:F, 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Facebook-D'!C2:C <> "", 'Facebook-D'!E2:E, IFERROR(REPLACE('Facebook-D'!E2:E, LEN('Facebook-D'!E2:E)-3, 4, "****")))), 
                 'Facebook-D'!G2:G}, ROW('Facebook-D'!A2:A), FALSE); SORT({'Instagram-D'!B2:B, 'Instagram-D'!A2:A, 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Instagram-D'!E2:E = "", "", IF('Instagram-D'!C2:C <> "", "Removed", "Processing"))), 'Instagram-D'!F2:F, 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Instagram-D'!C2:C <> "", 'Instagram-D'!E2:E, IFERROR(IF(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT('Instagram-D'!E2:E, "com/(.+)")) > 4, 
                 REPLACE('Instagram-D'!E2:E, LEN('Instagram-D'!E2:E)-3,4, "****"), 
                 REPLACE('Instagram-D'!E2:E, LEN('Instagram-D'!E2:E)-1,2, "**"))))), 'Instagram-D'!G2:G}, ROW('Instagram-D'!A2:A), FALSE); SORT({'TikTok-D'!B2:B, 'TikTok-D'!A2:A, 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF('TikTok-D'!E2:E = "", "", IF('TikTok-D'!C2:C <> "", "Removed", "Processing"))), 'TikTok-D'!F2:F, 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF('TikTok-D'!C2:C <> "", IFERROR(IF(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT('TikTok-D'!E2:E, "https://www.tiktok.com/@(.*?)/")) = 4, 
              REPLACE('TikTok-D'!E2:E, LEN("https://www.tiktok.com/@" & REGEXEXTRACT('TikTok-D'!E2:E, "https://www.tiktok.com/@(.*?)/"))-1, 2, "**"), 
              REPLACE('TikTok-D'!E2:E, LEN("https://www.tiktok.com/@" & REGEXEXTRACT('TikTok-D'!E2:E, "https://www.tiktok.com/@(.*?)/"))-3, 4, "****"))), 
            IFERROR(IF(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT('TikTok-D'!E2:E, "https://www.tiktok.com/@(.*?)/")) = 4, 
                           REPLACE(REPLACE('TikTok-D'!E2:E, LEN("https://www.tiktok.com/@" & 
                           REGEXEXTRACT('TikTok-D'!E2:E, "https://www.tiktok.com/@(.*?)/"))-1, 2, "**"), LEN('TikTok-D'!E2:E)-3, 4, "****"), 
                           REPLACE(REPLACE('TikTok-D'!E2:E, LEN("https://www.tiktok.com/@" & REGEXEXTRACT('TikTok-D'!E2:E, "https://www.tiktok.com/@(.*?)/"))-3, 4, "****"), LEN('TikTok-D'!E2:E)-3, 4, "****"))))), 'TikTok-D'!H2:H}, ROW('TikTok-D'!A2:A), FALSE); 
             SORT({'YouTube-D'!B2:B, 'YouTube-D'!A2:A, ARRAYFORMULA(IF('YouTube-D'!E2:E = "", "", IF('YouTube-D'!C2:C <> "", "Removed", "Processing"))), 'YouTube-D'!G2:G, 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF('YouTube-D'!C2:C <> "", 'YouTube-D'!E2:E, IFERROR(REPLACE('YouTube-D'!E2:E, LEN('YouTube-D'!E2:E)-3, 4, "****")))), 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REPLACE('YouTube-D'!F2:F, LEN('YouTube-D'!F2:F)-3, 4, "****")))}, ROW('YouTube-D'!A2:A), FALSE)}, 1, FALSE)
```

The YouTube array contains an extra column compared to the rest. Initially, it would fail because not all the arrays had the same number of columns in them. I solved it by inserting a blank column in each of the sheets and referencing that one (the last column reference in each array except YouTube, so 'Discord-D'!I2:I, 'Facebook-D'!G2:G, 'Instagram-D'!G2:G and 'TikTok-D'!H2:H). Is there a better way I can achieve this (for example by **creating a virtually blank column** instead of actually needing to have one in reality)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are various ways how to create a virtual column (or row). for example, to avoid [array errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58042211/5632629) we can create a virtual array manually like:

```
={A1:A5, {"";"";"";"";""}}
```

to do it dynamically we can use divide by zero error and turn it into blanks:

```
=IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0, )
```

another way is within query where we can insert virtual column as:

```
=QUERY(A:C, "select A,B,C,' ' label ' '''")
```

but you can do it even with a single if:

```
=IF(A2:A,,)
```

and a lot of people use a sequence with substitute:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A), 1, 1, 0), 1, )
```

of course, 2nd, 4th and 5th fx need `ARRAYFORMULA` wrapping

another popular way is to reference an existing column that is for sure empty like X:

```
={A:C, X:X}
```

and in some cases, you can even reference a non-existent column. 
for example, if your sheet has A-Z columns you can use:

```
={A:C, XX:XX}
```

and lambda lovers will appreciate:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(x/0))(A2:A))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, x)(IF(A2:A,,)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much player0, =IF(A2:A,,) worked like a charm! I tried ={A1:A5, {"";"";"";"";""}} in the past and did it again now, but that one is still not working for some reason. Getting this error: "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows." if I use {A1:A5, {""}} for one empty column~

Comment: - @Player0 No surprise, I have the same question when I saw the formula displayed like that, I quickly passed this question and stuck with the problem that I couldn't remember where I encountered it. ---I think going through this inquiry would be discouraging for the average user. on the other hand the response contain all of the correct answers,--- for a relatively easy question to follow through [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73881199/19529694)