# Adding empty column in an array in google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I have this [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w9ZwQgmr6bcC-iJPSBSdIT3GTWic-GXtuC3TIMFhRNA/copy) with an input table in Google Sheets.

| Keys | Tags | V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kEp | tag1 | 30 | 12 |
| PgZ | tag2 | 8 | 2 |
| pac | tag3 | 15 | 21 |

This is what i did; I added `REGEXREPLACE(QUERY({A1:D},"Select Col1"),".+"," ")` to get the empty column `I`

```
=ArrayFormula({
  QUERY({A1:D}," Select Col1,Col2,Col3 ",1),
  REGEXREPLACE(QUERY({A1:D},"Select Col1"),".+"," "),
  QUERY({A1:D}," Select Col1,Col2,Col4 ",1)})
```

[image]

**The ask**

Is there is a simple way with the **same range refrence** this case `A1:D` to add an empty column to the array `{}` like this `&""&` ?

Comment: how important is it that it be truly empty? because an (invisible) space would be pretty simple.

Comment: To be used multiple times without lambda limitation when the the data get larger, simple like `&" "&` invisible) space would do. if not it need to be retreaved and adjusted from the provided refrence.

Comment: [mattking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11075129/mattking) Answerd in [2022-09-28 13:33:59Z](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73882373/timeline#history_4b288c10-babc-45fb-90bd-4682436c8b9c) `AND`  [themaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) commented in [2022-09-28 13:33:51Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881199/adding-empty-column-in-an-array-in-google-sheets/73882373?noredirect=1#comment130456589_73882248), @MattKing , @themaster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 'empty' doesn't really have to be that empty, this is pretty simple...

```
=QUERY({A1:D4,A1:B4},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,' ',Col5,Col6,Col4 label ' '''")
```

[image]

Comment: woAow `Query`           - @mattKing

Comment: Yes Its good   [Shheeesh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdmt83vqUI4) in that sense

Comment: Very simple and tricky.

Comment: Explain this last bit `label ' '''`

Comment: @Osm get rid of it and see what happens.  That's the simplest way to explain it.

Comment: Yes Indeed     - @mattKing

Answer (score 1):

You can try-

```
={QUERY({A1:D}," Select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col1 is not null",1),
  FLATTEN(SPLIT((REPT(" |",COUNTA(A:A))),"|")),
  QUERY({A1:D}," Select Col1,Col2,Col4 where Col1 is not null",1)}
```

And simplified formula-

```
={QUERY(A:D,"select A,B,C where A is not null",1),
  FLATTEN(SPLIT((REPT(" |",COUNTA(A:A))),"|")),
  QUERY(A:D,"Select A,B,D where A is not null",1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get different cuts of the `r`an`g`e  through `OFFSET` and join them along with empty arrays crafted with `MAKEARRAY`:

```
=LAMBDA(rg,where,how_many,
  {
    OFFSET(rg,0,0,,where),
    MAKEARRAY(ROWS(rg),how_many,LAMBDA(r,c,)),
    OFFSET(rg,0,where,,COLUMNS(rg)-where)
  }
)(A1:INDEX(D:D,COUNTA(D:D)),1,2)
```

Comment: I m doing something similar now [see](https://i.imgur.com/YNRxC8u.png)

Comment: @Osm Nice  ⠀‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: @Osm I'm sure it could be simplified with query `select A, B, ' ', C,D`