# How to use dynamic array formula to filter and format data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am facing a problem related to the dynamic array.

I have data in the below format.

[image]

And I want to convert to this format.

[image]

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BkQoH9nTm3Tbad0TYWBIuh9wf9wtWX3U3iWT8LPRM9k/edit#gid=0) is the sheet link.

I am using this formula to filter Fruits category.
`={FILTER(A5:D11,B5:B11="Fruits");SUM( FILTER(D5:D11,B5:B11="Fruits"))}`

But it gives this error

> `In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows`

NOTE: Data should be pulled dynamically from the formula, as the data may change.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build the result table without hard coding category names in the formula, use the recently introduced lambda functions, like this:

```
={ 
  lambda( 
    data, categories, headers, totalsHeader, blankRow, selectPrice, 
    reduce( 
      headers, query(unique(categories), "where Col1 is not null", 0), 
      lambda( 
        resultTable, filterKey, 
        { 
          resultTable; 
          lambda( 
            filterData, 
            { 
              filterData; 
              { totalsHeader, query(filterData, selectPrice, 0) }; 
              blankRow 
            } 
          )(filter(data, categories = filterKey)) 
        } 
      ) 
    ) 
  )( 
    B5:D, 
    B5:B, 
    B4:D4, 
    { "", "Total:" }, 
    { "", "", "" }, 
    "select sum(Col3) label sum(Col3) '' " 
  ); 
  { "", "Grand Total:", sum(D5:D) } 
}
```

See [{ array expressions }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197), [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343), [reduce()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597) and [lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718).

The formula will repeat each category name on several rows. If they get in the way, you can hide them from view by using a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule.

Answer (score 2):

I did some tests to add all the information in just one formula. It will change the format you want, but it will still divide all the information.

Here is the formula:

```
={"Fruits:","";QUERY(B5:D,"select C, D where B ='Fruits'");
{"Total:",SUMIF(B5:D,"Fruits",D5:D)};"","";
"Vegetables:","";QUERY(B5:D,"select C, D where B ='Vegetables'");
{"Total:",SUMIF(B5:D,"Vegetables",D5:D);"","";
"condiments:","";QUERY(B5:D,"select C, D where B ='condiments'");
{"Total:",SUMIF(B5:D,"condiments",D5:D)};"","";
"Grand Total:",SUM(D5:D)}}
```

**Note:**
*I added `:` and the end of each category in the formula so they will look like `Fruits:` and the table will look like this:*

[image]

The formula opens with `{` to open an [array](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) in Google Sheets, and you use `,` to separate columns to write a row of data, and `;` to separate the rows to help you write a column of data. After that, you use `}` to close the array. For example:

```
{"1","2";"3","4"}
```

It will print:

[image]

So basically, I organize the data with arrays of the same amounts of columns. The first one with part

```
= {   => To open the array.
```

```
"Fruits:","";  => This create a cell with "Fruits:" + an empty cell.
```

```
QUERY(B5:D,"select C, D where B ='Fruits'");  => which is 
already on an array of 2 columns.
```

```
{"Total:",SUMIF(B5:D,"Fruits",D5:D)}; => Creates the "Total" cell + the sum 
of values that has Fruits in column B.
```

```
"","";  => Which will create an empty row to separate the information
for the next set of arrays.
```

You do the same pattern for the other categories.

```
}  => to end the initial array.
```

You can add a "[Conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413)" that will change the text with `:` to bold automatically.

[image]

**Reference:**

- [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58042211/5632629

the first part of your formula outputs a grid of 4×3 cells

the second part of your formula outputs a single cell

if you want to combine it properly use:

```
={FILTER(A5:D11, B5:B11="Fruits");
 {"","","Totals",SUM(FILTER(D5:D11, B5:B11="Fruits"))}}
```

or:

```
={FILTER(B5:D11, B5:B11="Fruits");
 {"","Totals",SUM(FILTER(D5:D11, B5:B11="Fruits"))}}
```