# Filtering a Sheet based on multiple outcomes/responses

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, spreadsheet, uppercase

I'm trying to filter a column based on two slightly different outcomes (included in the formula) but getting an array error message.

The code I'm trying to filter with is as follows. I've used a similar formula in the past which works when looking in different columns but I'm having trouble getting this to work without an error.

```
={FILTER('Tidy Form Responses'!A2:F,UPPER('Tidy Form Responses'!B2:B="Talk for Writing (29.03.2023)"));FILTER('Tidy Form Responses'!A2:F,UPPER('Tidy Form Responses'!B2:B="Talk for Writing (29.03.2023) FD"))}
```

Comment: In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

Comment: [Edit] the error into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58042211/5632629

but your error actually comes from wrapping the whole 2nd argument of each FILTER into UPPER

try:

```
={FILTER('Tidy Form Responses'!A2:F, 
   UPPER('Tidy Form Responses'!B2:B)=UPPER("Talk for Writing (29.03.2023)"));
  FILTER('Tidy Form Responses'!A2:F,
   UPPER('Tidy Form Responses'!B2:B)=UPPER("Talk for Writing (29.03.2023) FD"))}
```

Comment: This worked! It's a temporary solution as we change the wording so thank you!